# Understanding code from K&R

Tags: c, allocation, readlines

I'm reading K&R for my c language course, I have question in function readlines from section 5.6:

```
/*readlines: read input lines*/
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];

    nlines=0;
    while ((len=getline(line, MAXLEN))>0) //getline gets a line of chars and return its 
                                          //length. if the length is negative,
                                          // no line exits.
        if (nlunes>=maxlines || (p=alloc(len))==NULL) //alloc allocates storage for input
           return -1;
        else{
            line[len-1]='\0' //**THIS IS THE PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND**
            strcpy(p,line); //copies line into p (strings)
            lineptr(nlines++)=p;
            }
    return nlines; /*return number of lines we could read*/
```

So this function is part a sorting function that sorts an array of character lines in lexicographical order using qsort and pointers.

I don't understand particularly what following line does

```
line[len-1]='\0' //**THIS IS THE PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND**
```

Why do we have to delete "previous line" or "new line"?

Also, following isn't clean either:

```
p=alloc(len)
```

I understand we allocate storage for p which is a pointer. So we allocate appropriate storage for the length of the line in the memory. Is that correct?

Comment: where you get this code? There is something strange anyway.

Comment: You should read the part of the book that covers strings. If you know one basic property of C strings, this should be trivial.

Comment: @FelicePollano Read the question. It's in K&R.

Comment: H2CO3 it sound strange to me it shoolud be line[len]='\0' to properly terminate the string, isn't?

Comment: @FelicePollano `len` is treated throughout the code as if it included the terminating `NUL` byte.

Comment: @FelicePollano; No. It should be `line[len-1]='\0'`.

Comment: @alan why are you reverting the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line[len-1]='\0'
```

because `getline` puts `\n` in last character.

see in `getline` function
`if(c=='\n'){s[i]=c;++i;  }`

Also 
`p` is allocated to **block of length of `line`** so that line could be copied to to because `line` is used to store subsequent characters line, if it is not copied all line will be lost.

Comment: so line[len] is the place of the last char of the chars array, which is the string? @haccks

Comment: Last char which is `'\0'` will go to `line[len-1]`.

Comment: If you see `getline` defination then analyze :
 `s[len-1]='\n'` and `s[len]='\0'`.. logically if you include then `\n` in string definition then your length become `len` if not then `len-1` . In above code, you are not including `\n` in string, so your length become `len-1` home of `\0`

Answer (score 1):

> Does, why do we have to delete "previous line" or "new line"?

We don't. This is not `lineptr[len - 1]`, but `line[len - 1]`. It NUL-terminates the string, as C strings are expected to be NUL-terminated.

> so we allocate appropriate storage for the length of the line in the memory?

Yes, presumably, although I don't know what exactly `alloc()` does. Perhaps it's a typo (you have quite a few of them in the code), and you actually meant to write `malloc()`?

Comment: No, I was refering to alloc() which is a function k&r show in their book. Thank you!